# Webpack AotPlugin with multiple entryModules

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am trying to use AotPlugin with webpack. My web system (web application?) has 8 angular2 apps in it, which are controlling specific areas of the system. The webpack generates 9 bundles.

I managed to compile 1 app with AotPlugin, but I am struggling to understand how to AoT all 8 apps for production...

Have anyone done it?  Is there are other ways to achieve bundling and Aot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run ngc first, then plug in all aot starters into webpack.

here is an example project.

https://github.com/patrickhousley/angular2-multi-project-test

Here https://github.com/mcgri/NgMultiApp  I made a .NET 4.6 project which demonstrates how to do webpack + ngc (AoT compilation)